# How to iterate through nested dicts with dates as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to create a dataset with dates and closing prices for tickers so that my dataset will look the following:

```
                  AAPL
2019-01-01       157.92
2019-01-02       157.92
```

I have found an api that gives a json response of the following when requesting it:

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
print(data)

{'name': 'AAPL', 'history': {'2019-01-01': {'open': '154.89', 'close': '157.92', 'high': '158.85', 'low': '154.23', 'volume': '37039737'}}}
{'name': 'AAPL', 'history': {'2019-01-02': {'open': '154.89', 'close': '157.92', 'high': '158.85', 'low': '154.23', 'volume': '37039737'}}}
```

Since I need to go deep withing the nested dicts I have no clear understanding of how it should be done to extract the date and the closing price.

I have tried the following and variation of the following be snooping around on the internet, but haven't found a clear way of how it's done or how the logic works:

```
for k,v in data.items():
        print(k,v)
```

What is the way to go in this situation, and how is the logic structured?

SAMPLE FROM API: https://www.worldtradingdata.com/documentation#full-history

```
{
    "name": "AAPL",
    "history": {
        2019-04-12: {
            "open": "199.20",
            "close": "198.87",
            "high": "200.14",
            "low": "196.21",
            "volume": "27760668"
        },
        2019-04-11: {
            "open": "200.85",
            "close": "198.95",
            "high": "201.00",
            "low": "198.44",
            "volume": "20900808"
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Boris Totally agree with you there, thats we I'm here asking

Comment: I meant you should take time out of your day to read a book like Learn Python 3 the Hard Way or Automate the Boring Stuff With Python or at least [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: @Boris Thank you for your recommendations Boris, highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` to create a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name': 'AAPL',
    'history': {
        '2019-04-12': {
            'open': '199.20',
            'close': '198.87',
            'high': '200.14',
            'low': '196.21',
            'volume': '27760668'
        },
        '2019-04-11': {
            'open': '200.85',
            'close': '198.95',
            'high': '201.00',
            'low': '198.44',
            'volume': '20900808'
        },
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['history'], orient='index')
```

Which gives the following data frame:

```
              open   close    high     low    volume
2019-04-11  200.85  198.95  201.00  198.44  20900808
2019-04-12  199.20  198.87  200.14  196.21  27760668
```

Comment: I seem to get an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Comment: Do you get the error when you run the exact same snippet that I posted? Also from your questions the data structure was not really clear (is it list of dicts?) so maybe you could update it for clarification?

Comment: Yeah the exact same snippet. Above I show how I store the request I make. The JSON structure is exactly as I posted it above so it's just  dicts of dict and no lists. Thank you for your help and time! If anything is unclear please let me now.

Comment: @MisterButter Looking at your question you posted two dicts right below each other, without any surrounding data structure. So we can only guess what that means. Could you please add the exact data structure such that I can copy & paste into my Python interpreter? What version of Python and `pandas` are you running? I'm on Python 3.6 and `pandas==0.23.0`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I created, posted a sample of the JSON response that was on the API-site. I'm running Python 3.6.5 on Jupyter notebook and pandas 0.23.0. Hope this will help

Comment: @MisterButter Thank's for update. For that data structure the code even simplifies, please see my updated answer. In case you're still receiving that error I suggest you restart your kernel and try again.

Comment: Excellent solution, thank you so much for your patience and help.